# WPF TextChanged event fired only when I change the value

Tags: wpf

In my project I have several textboxes with a method binded to TextChanged event:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="12" Style="{StaticResource txtDataStyle1}" Width="100" TextChanged="Data_TextChanged">
    <Binding Path="ConfigObject.Edit.Default" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:GenericValidationRule>
                <local:GenericValidationRule.Wrapper>
                    <local:Wrapper TipoInterno="{Binding Path=Content, Source={x:Reference txtTipo}}"/>
                </local:GenericValidationRule.Wrapper>
            </local:GenericValidationRule>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</TextBox>
```

When the page loads and the textboxes are valorized with "ConfigObject.Edit.Default", the Data_TextChanged event is fired. How can omit it?
I would "use" that method only when I change its value. Any help?

Comment: You could manage this particular value in the Data_TextChanged() method: if( value == Default) return. It's not so clean as solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of handling the the `TextChanged` event in the view, you should implement your logic in the setter of the source property.

If you can't do this for some reason, you could simply return from the event handler if the `TextBox` hasn't yet been loaded:

```
private void Data_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (textBox.IsLoaded)
    {
        //your code...
    }
}
```